# taskscheduleR Status 16389

Tags: r

I'm using the taskschedulerR library and i get the following error. I'm trying to have R run a script nightly how can i fix this error or is there a better option?

How do you resolve this issue:

```
Warning in system(cmd, intern = TRUE) :
  running command 'schtasks /Create /TN "SalesByCustomerDetail_Report.R" /TR 
  "cmd /c C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.2/bin/Rscript.exe 
  \"C:/Analytics/analytics/SalesByCustomerDetail_Report.R\"  >> 
  \"C:/Analytics/analytics/SalesByCustomerDetail_Report.log\" 2>&1" 
  /SC DAILY /ST 10:10 /SD "17/02/2024" ' had status 16389
```

Comment: https://github.com/bnosac/taskscheduleR/issues/23, where "16389" allegedly means that the file is not found. If I had to guess (I do), I'd say that the `SalesByCustomerDetail_Report.R` is not in the directory where TaskScheduler normally operates from (which, iirc, is `c:/Windows/System32` or similar, and I'm doubting that your `.R` file is in that directory.